# Como fazer uma condição baseada na multiplicidade de elementos de um vetor na linguagem lawtex?

Tags: lawtex

Gostaria de fazer uma condição `(if)` baseada na multiplicidade de elementos de um vetor `(foreach)`. No entanto, não faço ideia de como. Peço auxílio prático de como fazer isso.
Seria algo como,

```
if (número de elementos IN vectorX é maior que 1) {
    print "isso"
}
```

Para contextualizar:

```
if (numero de autor IN vectorAutores é 1) {
    print "vem"
}
if (numero de autor IN vectorAutores é maior que 1) {
    print "vêm"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não ficou claro se você está tentando (1) fazer o print caso o `|vectorX|` possua mais de um elemento, ou (2) caso um autor específico apareça mais de uma vez no vetor.

Caso seja a primeira opção, pode usar o `tube` de `size()`, e nesse caso o código ficaria: (ref: [Tube Size](http://docs.lawtex.com.br/doku.php?id=size_tube))

```
if(|vectorX|.size() == 1) {
    print "vem"
}
else {
    print "vêm"
},
```

Claro que para esse caso em que a única coisa que você quer fazer é imprimir um valor diferente para cada condição, o [Tube PrintIf](http://docs.lawtex.com.br/doku.php?id=printf_tube) é mais adequado e resumido, e ficaria  assim:

```
print printIf(|vectorX|.size() == 1, "vem", "vêm"),
```

Agora se for a segunda opção, preciso entender melhor qual a `struct` que você está usando para o seu vetor, para te direcionar a melhor resposta.

Mas digamos que sua struct seja algo do tipo:

```
struct[Test] {
    name = "Test"
    request = "Test"
    fields {
        +[numAutor]: Integer,
        +[a]: String,
        +[b]: Currency
    }
}
```

E a declaração do seu vetor seja `+|vectorAutores|: Vector[Test]`. Nesse caso, se você quiser saber quantas vezes o autor com um código específico aparece no vetor, você precisa usar o [Tube Filter](http://docs.lawtex.com.br/doku.php?id=filter_tube), para filtrar todos os elementos do vetor com esse número específico, salvar em outro vetor, digamos o vetor `+|filtrado|: Vector[Test]` e ver a quantidade de elementos desse resultado, usando o `size()`:

```
|filtrado| = |vectorAutores|.filter([this.numAutor] == 1),

print printIf(|filtrado|.size() == 1, "vem", "vêm"),
```

Answer (score 0):

A operação que retorna a quantidade de elementos dentro de um vetor é

```
|nomeDoVetor|.size()
```

Exemplo:

Suponto o vetor |vetorExemplo| com 4 elementos.

Logo, |vetorExemplo|.size() equivale ao valor 4.

Ou seja, se você fizer a seguinte operação

```
print(|vetorExemplo|.size())
```

será printada na tela o número 4

Para fazer operações matemáticas, basta fazer a operação normal, mas usando o |vetorExemplo|.size() no lugar do número. Exemplo ainda com base no |vetorExemplo| com 4 elementos:

```
if(|vetorExemplo|.size() == 4){
    print("O vetor tem 4 elementos!!!")
}
```